# Looking for GPT prompt management tools

Tags: offline

In the process of using GPT, I will accumulate many prompts, some of which are frequently used. I want to use them as templates and quickly apply them.

Is there any software that can help manage prompt templates and quickly apply them?

PS: I hope it is cross platform. The term 'cross platform' here does not refer to 'cross operating system platforms', but can be applied to various GPT tools. For example, if it is a browser plugin that provides services by changing the web pages of OpenAI, then it is not cross platform because I cannot use it in Bing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://prst.ai. Mostly they provide self hosted version, but SaaS also available, as I know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Link only answers get deleted.  Please add some details or review or screenshots of/from it.